Stored Procedure always returns null when using "RETURN value". If I use "SELECT value", it returns value correctly
USE [FPY]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insupd_tblMRBHistory]    Script Date: 2024-12-19 7:25:36 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insupd_tblMRBHistory]
           (@BusinessUnit char(30)
           ,@PartNum char(25)
           ,@Description varchar(50)
           ,@Category char(4)
           ,@LotNum char(25)
           ,@LocationID int
           ,@StockMRB int
           ,@ExtendedCost decimal(7,2)
           ,@TransDate datetime
           ,@MRBDays int
           ,@Closed bit)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[tblMRBHistory]
    SET        [BusinessUnit] = @BusinessUnit,
               [PartNum] = @PartNum,
               [Description] = @Description,
               [Category] = @Category,
               [LotNum] = @LotNum,
               [LocationID] = @LocationID,
               [StockMRB] = @StockMRB,
               [ExtendedCost] = @ExtendedCost,
               [MRBDays] = @MRBDays,
               [Closed] = @Closed
    WHERE [PartNum] = @PartNum AND [LotNum] = @LotNum AND [LocationID] = @LocationID

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMRBHistory]
                   ([BusinessUnit],
                   [PartNum],
                   [Description],
                   [Category],
                   [LotNum],
                   [LocationID],
                   [StockMRB],
                   [ExtendedCost],
                   [TransDate],
                   [MRBDays],
                   [Closed])
             VALUES
                   (@BusinessUnit,
                   @PartNum,
                   @Description,
                   @Category,
                   @LotNum,
                   @LocationID,
                   @StockMRB,
                   @ExtendedCost,
                   @TransDate,
                   @MRBDays,
                   @Closed)
        RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 2
    END
END

Why does the Stored Procedure work when I change the RETURNs to SELECTs?

Your question is not clear. A SP can never "return" null - well maybe if it throws an exception. The return value will otherwise be 0 if not set. Maybe you are referring to the resultset being null? (which is quite different to a return value). You really need to show us how you are calling it and what you mean by returns null.

Read the documentation, it explains everything: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

In your script, if where you have RETURN you write SELECT, then what you are doing is SELECTing data and returning it as a (one row one column) dataset... and then continuing with the execution of the code in the stored procedure. (You can return multiple datasets.)
The RETURN statement, however, does not return datasets, it ends execution of the stored procedure and returns an integer value to the caller. That returned value will only be caught if you write the stored procedure call to capture it (I’m using “caught” and “capture” as informal terms, here.)
DECLARE @ReturnValue  INT

EXECUTE @ReturnValue = dbo.insupd_tblMRBHistory
 <parameters here>

PRINT @ReturnValue

Stored procedures always return an INTEGER value, there is no requirement to capture or account for it. For what value is returned by default, check out the documentation: EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)
